# Simple javascript wcf webservice call returns null for result on success

Tags: javascript, asp.net, wcf

I am trying to make a simple WCF web service call from javascript that returns a Boolean.

I have the scriptmanager in the page.

As shown below the call back result always returns null in the OnAssignSuccess javascript method.

I can provide the web.config if needed.

The diagnostic trace shows the Boolean being returned in the root but that is not part of the response as shown below.

> Here is the javascript code

```
function OnAssignBackup() {
   var employees = document.getElementById("<%=cmbBackup.ClientID%>");
   PT.UpdateBackupSupervisor(employees.value, OnAssignSuccess, OnAssignFailed);
}

function OnAssignSuccess(result) {
   alert('Successfully updated your backup supervisor ' + result);
   // result is null
}
```

> here is the simple web service

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class PT
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public bool UpdateBackupSupervisor(string backupUserGUID)
    {
        bool bRet = false;
    .
    .
    .
        return bRet;
    }
}
```

> here is the diagnostic trace

```
<MessageLogTraceRecord>
<Addressing xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/ServiceModel/Management/MessageTrace">
<Action>urn:PT/UpdateBackupSupervisorResponse</Action>
</Addressing>
<HttpResponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/ServiceModel/Management/MessageTrace">
<StatusCode>OK</StatusCode>
<WebHeaders>
<Content-Type>application/json; charset=utf-8</Content-Type>
</WebHeaders>
</HttpResponse>
<root type="object" xmlns="">
<d type="boolean">true</d>
</root>
</MessageLogTraceRecord>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by using a jquery ajax call as follows.

```
function OnAssignBackup() {
    var employees = document.getElementById("<%=cmbBackup.ClientID%>");
    $.ajax
        (
            {
                type: 'GET',
                url: '../../Services/PT.svc/UpdateBackupSupervisor',
                data: { backupUserGUID: employees.value },
                success: function (response, status, error) {
                    alert('Successfully Updated Backup Supervisor: ' + status);
                },
                error: function (request, status, error) {
                    alert('Update Backup Supervisor Failed with error: ' + error);
                }
            }
        );
}
```

I use a webHttp behavior in web.config.